# show the option of triggering my app

Tags: iphone

I noticed that there are some apps can show the option of triggering them when I touch and hold seconds over email attachment.

Just wonder how can I do like these?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through this [guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html). Basically, you will have to declare yourself as an app that handle the document type. If the users selects your app, you need to handle that.